# COM component targeting netstandard

Tags: c#, com, .net-standard

Is it possible to create a C# project to create a COM component and targeting netstandard?

We have this project and the COM component builds and works fine:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="ADODB">
    <Guid>{B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129}</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>6</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>1</VersionMinor>
    <Lcid>0</Lcid>
    <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
    <Isolated>False</Isolated>
    <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

There is an `ADODB` reference because we need to access SQL Server this way (legacy app). Nevermind.

Now if I change the target framework to `netstandard1.0` (or 1.1) all hell breaks loose on the compilation.

All nugets the IDE suggests to include don't solve the build problems and I can't find relevant information on the web.

I am mostly curious if this is possible and if there is any main advantage of doing so.

---

Some compilation errors:

- `ProgId` not found
- `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]` not found
- a lot of ADODB class definitions not found too

Comment: netstandard is a contract with a given version (1.0, 1.3, 2.0, etc. I would focus on 2.0 today, others are rather legacy) that's meant for cross-platform support. Adding a static COM reference to a netstandard project will make this useless in any other platform than Windows. But it could be helpful in scenario where you dynamically load that project assembly, if at runtime you detect you're running on Windows (and do something else if you detect you're running on another platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COM is only available on Windows. The netstandard defines a common base for many platforms, like Linux, macOS and mobile platforms supporting Xamarin.

Therefore it doesn't make sense to target a COM component at netstandard. If the COM component is only an optional part of your project and the rest should target netstandard, extract it and communicate with it through other means if it is available, for example by exposing it as a service.

Comment: It doesn't make sense advice not to use COM because it's only available on windows when COM should be used.

Comment: I didn't advise not to use COM. COM simply can't be used with netstandard.